# Word of the Day #1

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Test run of a possible series of "word of the day" riddles!

*With a light source, I resemble a star;*

*Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.*

*Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away -*

*Tell me, what am I, your word of the day?*

Comment: Given the "word of the day" title, the references to "stars", and the fact that May the fourth will be gone (sail away) "come the fifth", I can't help but think there's a Star Wars connection in here somewhere...

Comment: I also notice that Mars (the planet) resembles a star with the sun as a light source, and that if you wrap ("fortify") Mars you get a Mars "bar"... But not sure how mars relates to the 5th or sailing... (is there a probe with a solar sail being launched on the 5th?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll guess:

> Flower

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> Sunflower sort of resembles a star (sun = light source)

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> Wallflowers are shy and tend to be alone (walls can be fortified)

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away

> Mayflower was a sailing ship (May is the fifth month)

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for, well done! Keep in mind that the sun itself is a star. :)

Comment: @BaileyM I enjoyed this puzzle.  Can't wait for the next one!

Answer (score 12):

I'm going with the word

> **Port**

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> Ports generally are accompanied by lighthouses, which are a bright light in the dark, hence a "star".

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> Port wine is a fortified wine.

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away -

> This brings the two together - "the fifth" is, as JLee notes, a liquor measurement, and thus relates to port wine, while "sail away" links to the ocean port meaning.

Comment: This is why I love puzzling.SE - I get answers to my own questions I've never even considered. This isn't what I was going for, but a definite +1!

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking of

> the Moon

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> When it is ligthened by the sun, a satellite can look like a star

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> When it's full moon, we can't see anything else in the sky because of the gleam

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away

> Full Moon this month is May 4th, the Moon looks like a sail when it decreases

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> Han Solo (from Star Wars)

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> The light source is his blaster.

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> His "shield" is Chewbacca. He's alone in the bar when he faces Greedo.

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away -

> Before taking off, the Millennium Falcon's crew must be aboard. The standard one has 5 living beings: Han, Leia, Luke, Obi-Wan, Chewbacca.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Han Solo" isn't a word.

Comment: Whatever is written and has a meaning is a word, imo. You could say "Those are two words!" and I'll just answer "Then my answer is Solo".

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a stretch, but it keeps gnawing at the back of my mind so I'll give it a try.

> Musical note

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> When you need to play softer ("light source") after a sustained piece, you release the piano pedal. The mark for this resembles a star: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#/media/File:Music-pedalup.svg

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> This is another stretch, but if you read "fortified" as "make it 4/4", then in a common 4/4 measure the whole note is alone between the bars (*semibreve*)

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away

> In the 4/4 measure above, the arrival of the fifth note marks the end of the previous measure, so the sound slowly "sails away" in the air

I'm pretty sure there are better solutions out there though :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a

> **shot**

With a light source, I resemble a star;

> When light shines through a shot glass in a dark room, it can [sparkle like a star](https://www.google.com/search?q=light%20shot%20glass&safe=off&biw=1447&bih=880&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=fidIVbulCsuWgwS17IHICA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg). (some shot glasses more than others)

Once fortified, I'm alone at the bar.

> Fortify can mean "[to strengthen a drink with alcohol](https://www.google.com/search?q=fortified&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)"

Then, come the fifth, I shall sail away -

> When the shot glass is filled from [the fifth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_%28unit%29) of distilled liquor, it will "sail away" into a person's mouth

Tell me, what am I, your word of the day?