# Word of the Day #3

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

For the previous Word of the Day challenges, check out [Word of the Day #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/word-of-the-day-1) and [Word of the Day #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13372/word-of-the-day-2).

> *Add to me one and I'll become a mess;*
>   *Add to me six and I'll buy you a dress.*
>   *Add thirty-five, I'll get bolder and louder;*
>   *Add to me none, and I'm left as a powder.*
>
> *What am I?*

Comment: 1+6+35 = 42! The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As has been pointed out, this is referencing the Periodic table... but the other answers got the references backwards.

The answer is

> Ash

Add to me one and I'll become a mess;

> 1 on the periodic table is Hydrogen, H. H+ash = Hash, a synonym for mess.

Add to me six and I'll buy you a dress.

> 6 on the periodic table is Carbon, C. C+ash = Cash, something you buy a dress with.

Add thirty-five, I'll get bolder and louder;

> 35 on the periodic table is Bromine, Br. Br+ash = Brash, a synonym for "bold" and "loud".

Add to me none, and I'm left as a powder.

> This one is more literal, as Ash is a powder.

Comment: Exactly what I was going for, congrats. :)

Comment: Nice! I was trying "dust" from the last line, but didn't think of "ash" or of adding letters in the way you did. +1

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Carbon?

Add to me one and I'll become a mess;

> add Hydrogen to carbon and you get hydrocarbons like oil, which is very messy

Add to me six and I'll buy you a dress.

> Carbon bonded with itself can be a diamond

Add thirty-five, I'll get bolder and louder;

> Carbon and bromine make a purple color, which is bold.

Add to me none, and I'm left as a powder.

> I'm guessing this is graphite powder

Comment: We both came up with the idea of using the periodic table almost simultaneously! I was in the middle of writing my answer when yours went up.

Comment: Good instinct to go with the periodic table, but my answer is much more wordplay and much less science. Your fits perfectly, though! :)

Answer (score 5):

You are

> tantalum, number 73 in the periodic table.

*Add to me one and I'll become a mess;*

> Tungsten, number 74, is somewhat toxic.

*Add to me six and I'll buy you a dress.*

> Gold, number 79, is valuable.

*Add thirty-five, I'll get bolder and louder;*

> Hassium, number 108, is radioactive.

*Add to me none, and I'm left as a powder.*

> The major use of tantalum is as a metal powder in electronic components such as capacitors.

Comment: Good instinct to go with the periodic table as well! Again, my answer is much more wordplay and much less science - which is probably a good thing, because I didn't even know tantalum was used as a metal powder in capacitors until I read this. I guess you learn something new every day!

Comment: @BaileyM I didn't know that either - I had to do a lot of Wikipedia searching to write this answer!